# Использование std::move в списках инициализации

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор

Допустим, мы имеем класс, инициализация у которого тяжелая и делать конструктор перемещения так невыгодно (например, класс, резервирующий блок памяти про запас):

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&& other) noexcept :
    MyClass()
{
    this->swap(other);
}
```

Поэтому мы делаем конструктор перемещения сразу со списками инициализации:

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&& other) noexcept :
    m_field_1 {           other.field_1()  },
    m_field_2 { std::move(other.field_2()) },
    m_field_3 { std::move(other.field_3()) }
{
    // Очищаем other
}
```

**Вопрос**: а когда нам надо писать `std::move(...)` в списке инициализации? Например, понятно, что если тип `field_1` - `int` то в этом нет необходимости (кстати, а если написать - будут ли накладные расходы, помимо вызова функции приведения к `rvalue`?). Мы должны ориентироваться на то, поддерживает или нет тип поля перемещение, а если мы работаем с шаблоном? Как узнать будет ли перемещение полезно для этого типа?

Comment: @Abyx а нет ли какого-нибудь класса свойств, к примеру, определяющего возможность (или наличие к-ра перемещения) перемещения у типа?

Comment: @Abyx все понял, спасибо.

Comment: Напишите лучше `MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&&) noexcept = default` и всё будет хорошо